# How to passing variable from keycloak backend to account theme

Tags: java, themes, keycloak

I use keycloak 22.0.1
For account theme I use my own theme it was created according "Keycloak Man" [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extension/extend-account-console)
also I put index.ftl in a my theme root this file from keycloak.v2
And in index.ftl I try to get any my custom variable from back

```
${myCustomVar}
```

But didn't work.

It works for login theme, when I override
`org.keycloak.forms.login.LoginFormsProviderFactory` and then pass attributes
But for account it didn't work, also I used override

```
org.keycloak.theme.DefaultThemeManagerFactory
org.keycloak.theme.freemarker.DefaultFreeMarkerProviderFactory
org.keycloak.theme.ThemeResourceProviderFactory
```

but nothing is work for me, my overrided classes even didn't run I see it in debugger
Is it possible for account theme? And if possible what class I should override to pass vars.
Thanks in advance for any help!